# Prerequisites for Khovanov Homology

Tags: general-topology, homology-cohomology, knot-theory

I have studied Undergraduate Abstract Algebra (including Category Theory) and Point Set Topology. I wish to attend a seminar series next month on Khovanov Homology which will introduce basics of Knot Theory and Homology Theory on the way. 
Considering that, can anybody suggest me an independent but solid road map, considering my current knowledge to learn Khovanov Homology?

Thank You.

Comment: Try to read the first 15 pages of [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0201043). Keep going when you get stuck, but write down what you were having trouble with. Then tell us where you got stuck. This will help give you a focused answer.

Comment: That seems too tough for me. As I mentioned above, I don't know Knot Theory and asking for a learning roadmap covering that.